# How to set background color for react-native-checkbox library

Tags: react-native, checkbox, styling

How can i set the background-color for checkboxes library https://github.com/react-native-checkbox/react-native-checkbox?

I use iOS as a platform.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

use `tintColor` prop to set color of the box when the checkbox is Off.

use `onCheckColor` prop to set color of the check mark when it is On.

use `onFillColor` prop to set color of the inside of the box when it is On.

use `onTintColor` prop to The color of the line around the box when it is On.

the value of above mentioned props will be hexadecimal value of color.

For example

```
<CheckBox
onFillColor={"#FF5733"}
disabled={false}
value={toggleCheckBox}
onValueChange={(newValue) => setToggleCheckBox(newValue)}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i dont want to fill the color when the checkobx is checked. As default i want the background color "white". I can use "tintColor" but only for the border of the checkbox. But how can a change the background-color when the checkbox it not checked?

Comment: @iSaBo You can try this
Wrap the checkbox in a View
use a state variable lets say `isChecked` to control checkbox
set the background color of View conditionally like this
<View
style={{
backgroundColor: isChecked? 'red' : 'white'
}}
>
//Your checkbox code
</View>